# L'accord du participe passé avec être (parents lesbiennes)

Tags: accord, genre, participe-passé, société

Si mes parents sont lesbiennes, comment est-ce que j'écris l'accord du participe passé?

> Mes parents **sont partis** à Nantes.

ou

> Mes parents **sont parties** à Nantes.

Comment: « Si mes parents sont lesbiennes » est incorrect. Il faut dire  « Si mes parents sont lesbiens » (voir par exemple https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre_gay_et_lesbien ), sinon «  Si mes parents sont des lesbiennes ».

Comment: You could borrow some terminology from that famous ‘French’ family, the “[Coneheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coneheads),” and say:
«Mes *unités parentales* sont parties pour Remulak ce matin ... Mibs, je voulais dire *à Nantes*»!

Comment: Rectification, « Si mes parents sont lesbiennes » est correct car d'une part lesbiennes ne peut pas être adjectif ici (l'adjectif signifie relatif au lesbianisme) et d'autre part le substantif lesbienne tel qu'utilisé ici n'admet pas de masculin. Si en revanche les parents en question habitaient l'île de Lesbos, on pourrait bien dire « Si mes parents sont lesbiens ».

Comment: Le mot "lesbienne" est quand même connoté assez péjorativement, et évoque surtout la sexualité des personnes. Quand on parle de parents, il est bien plus respectueux de dire "des parents du même sexe", ou d'employer des périphrases telles que "une famille homoparentale".

Answer (score 10):

Je dirais qu'il faut dire

> Mes parents sont partis à Nantes

car parent est un nom masculin.

Cependant, le mot parente existe. Tu pourrais dire :

> Mes parentes sont parties à Nantes.

Je n'ai jamais entendu ce terme et ça ne sonne pas bien.

Comment: "parente" peut être utilisé en informatique oui, en disant "c'est la classe parente de l'objet". Mais c'est vrai que ça choque pour désigner les liens familiaux...

Comment: Que les parents soient 2 femmes, 2 hommes ou un lévrier afghan et un poisson rouge, le mot "parent" étant masculin, l'accord se fait donc au masculin, pas besoin de mettre ta réponse au conditionnel :-)

Comment: « Mes parentes sont parties » désignerait des membres de la famille plus ou moins éloignée (des cousines par exemple). C'est un sens différent du mot *parent* (qui lui peut tout à fait être féminin @LaurentS.).

Comment: @Gilles > "Une parent" peut être correct ? Au temps pour moi dans ce cas...

Comment: @LaurentS. Non, une parentE. [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parent) I.A (le sens le plus courant, qui est toujours masculin, est I.B).

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec cette réponse, car "parente" existe bien, mais veut dire totalement autre chose!

Answer (score 5):

*Parent* est un mot pratique qui se substitue à *père et mère*. Il n'a pas de raison d'être dans le contexte proposé.

> Mes mères/mamans sont parties à Nantes.

Comment: Oui, mes mamans, c'est ce qui serait le moins ambigu, plutôt que d'utiliser le mot "parent" si vraiment ça dérange la personne.

Comment: Le terme [*parent*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parent) ne se substitue pas du tout à *père* et *mère* en tant que mot utilisable au singulier. Par ailleurs, rien n'indique que pour le terme qui ne s'emploie qu'au pluriel qu'il doive s'agir des géniteurs, on parle aussi de parents adoptifs...

Comment: @GAMPUB: je ne comprends pas la remarque à propos des géniteurs: Comme vous le relevez, _parents_ peut être entendu au sens juridique. Mais je doute que _mamans_ puisse être entendu au sens biologique.

Comment: => Le mot en question *parents* a toutes les raisons d'être utilisé dans le contexte proposé.

Answer (score 4):

La plupart des familles comportent un père et une mère, on entend donc majoritairement le terme "mes parents".
Quand on parle de sa mère, on n'utilise jamais "ma parente".
Donc utiliser "mes parentes" sera choquant à l'oreille car c'est un terme que l'on n'aura jamais entendu avant.

Il y a donc à mon avis 4 choix :

- Utiliser "mes parentes sont **parties** à Nantes" exactement de la même façon qu'on dirait "mes parents", mais la personne en face peut ne pas comprendre, ou demander d'expliquer
- Utiliser "mes parentes sont **parties** à Nantes", mais en rajoutant un contexte pour bien être sûr que la personne en face sache que l'on parle d'un couple lesbien, et qui comprendra donc sans difficulté que l'on utilise "parente". Cela aura l'avantage de faire évoluer les mœurs petit à petit pour que cela devienne commun
- Tout simplement "Mes parents sont **partis** à Nantes".
- Utiliser un autre terme si cela n'a pas d'importance, "mes mères sont **parties** à Nantes", "mes daronnes sont **parties** à Nantes" (si argot), "ma famille est **partie** à Nantes"...

Answer (score 1):

On ne peut absolument pas écrire grammaticalement "parent lesbienne".

Même si ici ça fait sens, grammaticalement, il est impossible d'avoir un nom qui est un masculin ou un neutre (ici un neutre), et **un accord qui sort de nulle part** au féminin.

"Parents lesbiens": C'est la forme grammaticalement correcte, et au niveau du sens, on comprend, par le mot "lesbien", qu'il s'agit de 2 femmes. Un homme ne pouvant pas être "lesbien".

Si la formulation "parents lesbiens" ne convient pas à la personne qui voulait l'employer, on peut trouver des alternatives, mais jamais d'accord avec un féminin non présent grammaticalement.

- Le mot "parente" n'a absolument pas le même sens que le mot "parent", "parente" n'est **pas** le féminin de parent, mais ce sont 2 mots qui ont des significations différentes.

Parent = a deux sens

Sens 1: père et mère. Dans ce cas il est toujours de forme masculine. *Mes parents*. Comme la précédente définition de "parents" incluait toujours au moins un masculin, il n'y avait pas de problème.

Sens 2:
Parent, Parente = désigne la parenté proche, à  l'exclusion de la cellule familiale proche, des pères et mères, frères et sœurs quand on l'utilise avec le déterminant "un". Exemple: 
*Je vais visiter un parent*. Ici on comprend qu'il ne s'agit pas du père ou de la mère, ou des frères et sœurs, mais d'un oncle, une tante, un cousin, un neveu, etc...
*Je vais visiter une parente*: même chose.

http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/parent/58139?q=parent

On ne peut donc pas utiliser le mot "parente" à la place du féminin de "parent" qui n'existe pas et qui mènerait à des confusions avec l'autre mot et son autre sens.

*Mes parentes sont parties à Nantes* -> On suppose que ce sont tes tantes ou autre.

Comment: La toute première partie semble ne pas prendre en compte le fait qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un accord mais d'une apposition de nom comme pour les soit-disant adjectifs de couleur composés : une lampe bleu marine, bleu ciel. Une sorte de question bateau...

Answer (score 0):

On ne peut pas écrire « **<s>Mes parents sont parties à Nantes</s>** »  car il y a une faute d'accord. On doit écrire « **Mes parents sont partis à Nantes** » ou, si son interlocuteur ne sait pas déjà que ce sont deux femmes et que l'on souhaite le souligner « **Mes parents, elles sont parties à Nantes** » ou « **Mes (deux) mères sont parties à Nantes** » comme on dirait « **Mes grands-mères sont parties à Nantes** ».

« **Parent(s)** », quand il signifie toute combinaison de pères, mères, parents adoptifs, légitimes, naturels, biologiques, spirituels, voire lévriers afghans ou poissons rouges ;-) , a toujours été utilisé uniquement au masculin mais il est vrai que la possibilité d'avoir deux mères est récente. C'est seulement quand il signifie personne(s) faisant partie de l'ensemble ce celles avec qui on a un lien de parenté direct ou indirect qu'il est normalement utilisé au féminin, le cas échéant.

Cependant, si le fait que ses parents sont deux femmes ne fait aucun doute pour ses interlocuteurs et qu'il n'y a pas de risque de confusion, je ne vois pas d'objection **grammaticale** à dire « **Mes parentes sont parties à Nantes** », de la même manière que l'on peut dire « **Une réunion de parentes d'élèves** » quand seules les mères des élèves en question y sont conviées. Il n'existe bien qu'une seule entrée dans le dictionnaire pour les substantifs **parent**, **parente**, **parents** et **parentes** et nous ne sommes donc pas là dans un cas d'homonymie. Le féminin existe bien déjà contrairement par exemple à **agente** ou **sergente** où cette objection grammaticale peut exister. Il existe en revanche des objections sémantiques car cette utilisation peut surprendre son interlocuteur, comme le fait d'avoir deux mères peut aussi le surprendre. Il existe finalement aussi des objections idéologiques à l'utilisation de **parentes** puisqu'on aborde ici un sujet politiquement sensible.

Comment: Pourquoi ces votes négatifs ?

Comment: Je ne sais pas. Je suis en partie d'accord avec cette réponse, sauf pour le "parentes" qui est un mot qui a une toute autre signification en français.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE « Qui a une tout autre signification » est exagéré. Une signification courante du substantif pluriel «[parentes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parente)» est «femmes qui font partie de ma famille», ce qui n'est pas foncièrement inexact dans le cas de la question. PS: Dans l'expression « tout autre signification », « tout » est un adverbe et ne prend donc pas le féminin.

Comment: Dans les réunions de parents d'élèves, on ne convie pas les membres de la famille mais plutôt les parents juridiques, ceux qui ont la garde des enfants concernés. Mes parentes sont parties à Nantes ou une réunion de parentes d'élèves ne constituent pas vraiment des équivalents des deux expressions visées, leur référence est beaucoup moins spécifique.

Comment: Non, ce n'est pas exagéré, même si c'est dans le même domaine. J'explique: Parent veut dire, la mère et le père, comme sens premier, ceux qui m'élèvent, dans ce cas il ne se met JAMAIS au féminin.

Comment: Un autre mot existe, qui est un homonyme, mais n'a pas le même sens, qui désigne la parenté. Comme lorsqu'on dit, je visite des parents (quelques fois, on précise."éloignés"), ce qui ne veut pas du tout dire la même chose. Quand on parle de "mes parents", avec le possessif, c'est le couple père-mère, les gens qui élèvent, quand on parle de: je vais voir DES parents. Le sens n'est pas le même, le mot n'est pas le même. Ce sont des homonymes, qui ont un sens complètement différents. Là cela peut se mettre au féminin.

Comment: Oui, je connais l'usage de "tout", mais j'écris vite, surtout au clavier, quand je ne me relis pas, c'est ce qui arrive, et je ne relis pas les commentaires, les réponses, oui.

Comment: @GAMPUB Je suis tout à fait d'accord. Dans le cas habituel (99.999..% des cas), « mes parentes » et « de parentes d'élèves » ont des significations bien définies et distinctes. C'est précisément pourquoi j'ai commencé mon dernier paragraphe par « Cependant, **si le fait que ses parents sont deux femmes ne fait aucun doute pour ses interlocuteurs et qu'il n'y a pas de risque de confusion** ».

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE: Quant tu parles d'homonymes c'est exagéré. Des homonymes sont des mots *différents* qui s'écrivent ou se prononcent pareil. Ici c'est bien le même mot (même étymologie) mais qui s'emploie avec des sens différents selon le contexte (ceci étant je partage ton analyse sur le reste...)